# Not sure if it's a memory leak (ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm writing custom animations and I suspect that I have a memory leak, but I'm not sure. Every time I run a given animation memory goes up a little, but it doesn't go down. To make sure, I made a test:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.weakanim);

// The animation collection to run
HyAnimationCollection * collection = [[HyAnimationCollection alloc] init];

self.weakanim = collection;
```

First this logs `nil` then it always logs an address. So there are two indicators here:

1. Memory starts at 9.7MB and goes up 0.1MB every 10 runs of the animation. I tested this to about 12MB. Now, should the memory be freed every time or is it just that ARC (like, say, JVM's garbage collector) only releases memory periodically? That is, maybe it isn't a leak, but instead ARC has not released it yet because I didn't reach a certain amount.
2. I declared `weakanim` as `weak` just to see if the previous animation collection was being released, but the same issue still arises: is ARC not releasing *yet*?

Comment: Seems like a leak from your description. Use Instruments to understand what is not being released. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: What an awesome tool! It's already pinned to my dock. Still studying it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ARC doesn't work like a JVM. The closest you get is when it uses the "autorelease pool." In this case, objects won't be related until the end of the run loop. If you can see the animation running then the run loop is most likely running and the pool should be flushed periodically.
2. A better way of showing whether there's a leak would be to put a breakpoint in the `dealloc` method of your `HyAnimationCollection` class. If the rest of your investigation is correct, my guess is that it's never called. You probably have a retain cycle in *that* code.

Comment: But if the pool is flushed periodically, how can I be sure that the dealloc method was already supposed to be called? Also, should I just override `dealloc`? I can't call `[super dealloc]`, as ARC forbids it.

Comment: It's not "periodically" in the same way that a garbage collector works "periodically." Basically, if your app is responsive -- animations running, taps on screen being responded to -- the run loop is working and the autorelease pool is being drained. And yes, when using ARC you just override `dealloc`.

Comment: I see. Then it's a leak.

Comment: @AndréFratelli when overriding `-dealloc` under ARC, don't call `[super dealloc]`. `[super dealloc]` is called automatically by ARC at the end of `-dealloc`, and also all `__strong` iVars are released. ( See also: [ARC docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) )